# out of memory exception on new bitmap

Tags: .net, vb.net, resources

in my own application i run an "update" function every 5 seconds, on a timer elapsed event.
This function, fired every 5 sec, updates 45 picturebox images with a variable state "...StatoBrucitore". I can also force this function with a redraw button on the interface; on a stress test, when i clicked this function many times, i have noticed an "out of memory exception".
Here is the code:

```
Select Case Essiccatoio.RegTemp(Ireg).StatoBruciatore
    Case eStato.sOFF
        NomeFile = Trim("FlameOff.png")
        NomeFile = Percorso & "\Immagini\" & NomeFile
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(NomeFile) Then
            Dim bm As New Bitmap(NomeFile)
            PictBruc(Ireg).BackgroundImage = bm
            PictBruc(Ireg).Image = Nothing
        End If
    Case eStato.sAccensione
        NomeFile = Trim("FlameTransitorio.gif")
        NomeFile = Percorso & "\Immagini\" & NomeFile
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(NomeFile) Then
            Dim bm As New Bitmap(NomeFile)
            PictBruc(Ireg).BackgroundImage = Nothing
            PictBruc(Ireg).Image = bm
        End If
    Case eStato.sRegime
        NomeFile = Trim("FlameTransitorio.png")
        NomeFile = Percorso & "\Immagini\" & NomeFile
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(NomeFile) Then
            Dim bm As New Bitmap(NomeFile)
            PictBruc(Ireg).BackgroundImage = bm
            PictBruc(Ireg).Image = Nothing
        End If
End Select
```

Note that the in middle case "eStato.sAccensione" is an animated gif, so i can't use a listimage instead of this approach cause i could lost the animation.
I think the problem is the continuous "new Bitmap"...
Anyone has a suggested option to resolve this exception?

Thanks for help

Comment: What is `PictBruc()`?  It doesnt look like you are disposing of any of the bitmaps created.  You might be able to see GDI objects rise and rise in TaskManager

Comment: (Setting a Disposable object to Nothing doesnt dispose of it, and doing so on the `Image` Property wont affect a bitmap assigned to `BackgroundImage`.  I am pretty sure your code is leaking),

Comment: PictBruc() is a picturebox array; these picturebox are always visibile on The main form.

Comment: Each picturebox will assume a different bitmap on The variabile state of The select case. So, how to fix this raise? I assume that a variable declared into a function, then on The exit of The function should it be automatically disposed with The GUI.

Comment: The post mentions 45 picture boxes, but there are only 3 shown.  Is that code just a sample portion or are there 42 others doing something similar?  And did you verify the leak with Task Manager?

Comment: This post is just a sample portion, The array of picturebox has 45 elements. This routine is looped for each elementi; each picturebox can assume these three bitmap. Think a form with 45 picturebox that represent The state of 45 burners. For each burner i would like to represent his state (on, off or starting).. Each state is a differenti graphic file.

Comment: ...`And did you verify the leak with Task Manager?`

Comment: An object implementing IDisposable (like Bitmap) won't be disposed when out of scope (or more exactly the part of **unmanaged** memory it uses won't be, only the managed part (handled by the GC))

Comment: And what about The garbage colector, instead of it should i dispose each graphic object into a called function?

Comment: I have not verified The manager yet, cause i am noto in fronte of The PC.. I'll update you as soon ad possibile

Comment: `And what about The garbage colector, instead of it.. `  thats not how it works.  Invoking the `Dispose` method on things which allocate resources is **how** GC knows you are done with it so it can release any resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a *new* bitmap with the line:

```
 Dim bm As New Bitmap(NomeFile)
```

...but you are not disposing of any previous images.  Doing this on a 5 second timer for 45 objects means *many* new objects per minute.  Eventually you wont be able to create any more and get the error.

---

Since you are assigning one of the same three images, there is no reason to recreate those bitmaps over and over and over.  More fundamentally, for 12 picture boxes to show the same image, you dont need 12 different `Bitmap` objects.

Load the images into an array somewhere at the start of the program:

```
Private BurnerImgs(2) As Image

' load the array somewhere like form load:
BurnerImgs(0) = Image.FromFile("...")
BurnerImgs(1) = Image.FromFile("...")
BurnerImgs(2) = Image.FromFile("...")
```

Then assign a given picturebox from there:

```
PictBruc(Ireg).Image = BurnerImgs(0)
```

---

If the images were members of Resources, you'd want to do the same thing.  The `GetObject()` method used to fetch images from resources creates a new image object.  So, assigning from resources repeatedly can result in the same issue.

Its a bit easier to load an array from `My.Resources` though:

```
Private BurnerImgs As Image()
...
BurnerImgs = New Image() {My.Resources.FlameOn,
                          My.Resources.FlameOff, 
                          My.Resources.WhiteHotFlame}
```

Comment: I have verified in The task manager if there is a leak on GDI number. There is not. The number of gdis is a constant. The exception i noticed is about noto enough memory and on debug mode it happened on The row labelling "new" bitmap. Is there another matter with memory? Or i am looking on The right way ?

Comment: Often with that error, the term "memory" is used loosely and it can actually mean you are out of resources.  Since it wont let you create a new bitmao, that would seem to be the case.  VS has a analysis and profiler tools which will help find these.  They are sometimes less obbious than the one you present.

Comment: I don' t understand this latter reply. Is The out of memory exception caused really from this "new bitmap" instruction?

Comment: If that is the line that is throwing the exception, then yes - at some point eventually it cannot create a new bitmap.  The *text* of the message though need not *really* mean memory - it *can* mean it is out of GDI handles, or memory is so fragmented that it cannot allocate a contiguous block for the new image.  No matter the real meaning, the answer is to Dispose of things when you are done with them or minimize how many objects you create

Answer (score 0):

Before assigning a new Bitmap to your picture boxes make sure you call **Dispose()** on the existing one.

```
If PictBruc(Ireg).Image isnot nothing then PictBruc(Ireg).Image.Dispose
```